# How do you change all images dimensions to have the same size?

Tags: images

I am trying to achieve this look without going into a photo editing app and cutting and pasting the image to the exact size.

I don't mind if half the image is gone as long as we can retain that image dimension and the scale.
[image]

Comment: How are you using/adding these images? Please add some kind of code. You should use thumbnails, then all images are with same dimensions **+** you don't need full size images in list: it would save a lot of bandwidth and would drastically decrease loading times.

Comment: Reading [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Media_Screen) should explain the basic knowledge behind uploading/adding media(images) and the standard 3 options for input (setting sizes) which wp offers out of the box. Next you could read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails). And [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) is also a good source. As N00b also asked, what did you try, which code is used. Did you actually do some research yourself, if so, what is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a new image size with [`add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

```
// Hard crop left top

add_image_size( 'custom-size', 160, 90, array( 'left', 'top' ) );
```

Then use a plugin like [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) which will automatically create the new sizes on your server.

You can also make your custom sizes selectable from your WordPress admin. To do so, you have to use the [`image_size_names_choose`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/image_size_names_choose) hook to assign them a normal, human-readable name.

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'wpse_20160116_custom_sizes' );

function wpse_20160116_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'custom-size' => __( 'Your Custom Size Name' ),
    ) );
}
```

For featured images make sure to use [`add_theme_support( ‘post-thumbnails’ );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) and then access the new size using [`the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail):

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-size' ); 
}
```

For other images you can use [`wp_get_attachment_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/):

```
// Assuming your Media Library image has a post id of 42...

echo wp_get_attachment_image( 42, 'custom-size' );
```

As @Charles points out, you should be able to see your new size on the [Media Settings Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Media_Screen).

[image]